# In Kubernetes node affinity what is IgnoredDuringExecution?

Tags: kubernetes

In "requiredDuringSchedulingIgnoredDuringExecution", I understand what is required during scheduling but what is Ignored during execution.

Answer (score 4):

`requiredDuringSchedulingIgnoredDuringExecution` has two components:

1. `requiredDuringScheduling` implies that the pod should be scheduled on the node only if it satisfy the criteria.
2. `IgnoredDuringExecution` implies that if any pod is already `Scheduled` and `Running` on some node then it should not be evicted due to the changes in labels on a node at runtime and only the new pods should be required to match the new criteria.